# merging multiple repositories as subdir of a new repository

Tags: python-3.x, git, powershell, github

I have 3 repositories old_a, old_b, old_c and would like to merge them to a new repository new_d as sub directories without losing the file/commit history

Created following script using an article I found online, assuming that I am in the directory of the new repository "new_d"

```
# create a new repo

git init

# create a dummy commit to initiate the new repository

dir > deleteme.txt
git add .
git commit -m 'Initial dummy commit'

# add remote for and fetch the old repo

git remote add -f old_a <old_a ssh link>
git merge old_a/master

# removing the dummy file, it is not needed anymore

git rm ./deleteme.txt
git commit -m 'clean up initial file'

# Moving old repo files and folders into a subdirectory so they don’t collide with the 
other repo coming later

mkdir old_a
dir -exclude old_a | %{git mv $_.Name old_a}

# Commit the files and folders moving

git commit -m 'Move old_a files into subdir'

# Same repeated for all remote repositories need to be moved to the new repo as subdir
git remote add -f old_b <old_b ssh link>
git merge old_b/master
mkdir old_b
dir -exclude old_a, old_b | %{git mv $_.Name old_b}
git commit -m 'Move old_b files into subdir'
```

When I execute the script I can see the repo remoting to the original 3 old repos and that sub directories created on my local machine however these subdirectories are empty, the files folders in the original old repos are not being fetched into the new one. Am I missing something? Do I need to add clone to each of the subdirectories to get the folders/files from the original?

Thanks

Comment: Read about git subtree and use it

Comment: Note that the history *in* a Git repository consists of the *commits* in the repository. These commits are uniquely numbered (with hash IDs that are computed by hashing the contents of the commits). You can indeed use git-subtree to combine multiple commits together, but note that git-subtree itself is not well maintained.